# ProGuard causes SSL handshake error on Android

Tags: android, ssl, proguard

My App behaves well without obfuscation (specifically WITH -dontobfuscate enabled in ProGuard), but as soon as enable obfuscation, SSL queries fail with such error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms:418)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:212)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1322)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1410)
at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:131)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:484)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:465)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
```

Any ideas which class could be causing it?

ProGuard config:

```
-dontoptimize
#-dontobfuscate
# Preverification is irrelevant for the dex compiler and the Dalvik VM.
-dontpreverify
-ignorewarnings
#-printusage "usage.txt"
# usunięte z powodu crashlytics
#-printmapping "out.map"

# Reduce the size of the output some more.
#-repackageclasses ''
#-allowaccessmodification

# Switch off some optimizations that trip older versions of the Dalvik VM.
#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic

# Keep a fixed source file attribute and all line number tables to get line
# numbers in the stack traces.
# You can comment this out if you're not interested in stack traces.
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# RemoteViews might need annotations.
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Preserve all fundamental application classes.
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

# Preserve all View implementations, their special context constructors, and
# their setters.
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

# Preserve all classes that have special context constructors, and the
# constructors themselves.
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

# Preserve all classes that have special context constructors, and the
# constructors themselves.
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
    public void *(android.view.View);
    public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

# Preserve the special fields of all Parcelable implementations.
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}

# Preserve the required interface from the License Verification Library
# (but don't nag the developer if the library is not used at all).
-keep public interface com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# The Android Compatibility library references some classes that may not be
# present in all versions of the API, but we know that's ok.
-dontwarn android.support.**

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration
# classes.

-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
# You can comment this out if your application doesn't use serialization.
# If your code contains serializable classes that have to be backward 
# compatible, please refer to the manual.

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keep class * implements org.xml.sax.EntityResolver

-keepclassmembers class * {
    ** MODULE$;
}

####################################################################################################
# moje
####################################################################################################

# -keep public class mypackage.MyClass
# -keep public interface mypackage.MyInterface
# -keep public class * implements mypackage.MyInterface

# bo animatory
-keepclassmembers class pl.qus.** {
    public void set*(...);
    public *** get*();
}
-keep class pl.qus.xenoamp.fragment.** { *; }
# chyba konieczne dla adapterów używanych w ciele withView<>()
-keep class pl.qus.xenoamp.adapter.** { *; }
-keep class pl.qus.clients.model.** { *; }



# Crashlytics
#-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
#-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception

# Event Bus
-keepclassmembers class pl.qus.** {
    public void onEvent*(**);
}

# audiotagger
-keep class org.jaudiotagger.** { *; }

####################################################################################################
# nie-moje
####################################################################################################

# gson-xml
-keep class stanfy.** { *; }

# jcifs
-keep class jcifs.** { *; }

# cling
-keep class org.fourthline.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
#-keep class nurik.wizard.** { *; }

# textSurface
-keep class su.levenetc.android.textsurface.** { *; }

# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
# bez tego kotlinowe lambdy będą się jebać!
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

# Green dao
-keepclassmembers class * extends de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao {
     public static java.lang.String TABLENAME;
 }
-keep class **$Properties

# play services
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

# spotify
-keep class com.spotify.** { *; }

# jsoup
-keep class org.jsoup.** { *; }

-keep class tv.danmaku.ijk.** { *; }
```

The request is made like this:

```
    val respons = Rest.getResponse(
            method = "GET",
            protocol = scheme,
            host = host,
            path = "/rest/ping.view",
            query = prepareStdArgs(),
            port = port
    )
```

With such code:

```
fun getResponse(method: String = "GET",
                protocol: String = "https",
                host: String,
                path: String,
                query: Map<String, String> = hashMapOf<String, String>(),
                headery: MutableMap<String, String> = hashMapOf<String, String>(),
                allowRedirects: Boolean = false,
                postContents: String = "",
                useCache: Boolean = true,
                wait: Long = 0,
                port: Int = -1): RestResponse {
    if (!useCache) {
        Thread.sleep(wait)
    }
    val connection = getConnection(method, protocol, host, path, headery, query, port) as HttpURLConnection
    if (!allowRedirects)
        connection.instanceFollowRedirects = false

        return connection.obtainRestResponse(postContents, useCache).apply { connection.disconnect() }

}

private fun getConnection(method: String, protocol: String, host: String, path: String, headery: MutableMap<String, String>, query: Map<String, String>, port : Int = -1): URLConnection {
    if(protocol=="https") {
        val sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS") // bylo: SSL
        sc.init(null, XenoHttpClient.trustAllCerts, java.security.SecureRandom())
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.socketFactory)
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier { s, sslSession -> true }
    }
    var connection = buildUrl(protocol, host, path, query, port).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    connection.requestMethod = method
    if (!headery.containsKey("User-Agent"))
        headery.put("User-Agent", "curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23")

    connection.applyHeaders(headery)
    connection.useCaches = false

    return connection
}

private fun HttpURLConnection.obtainRestResponse(postContents: String = "", useCache: Boolean = true): RestResponse {

    if (postContents.isNotBlank()) {
        this.doOutput = true
        Logger.d("POST contents:$postContents")
        DataOutputStream(this.outputStream).let {
            it.writeBytes(postContents)
            it.flush()
            it.close()
        }
    }

    this.connect()

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) {
        val kesz = XenoFile(XenoAmp.cacheDir(),
                XenoUtility.md5(this.url.toString()))

        var cachingReq = false

        var istream = if (this.requestMethod.toUpperCase() != "GET") {
            // nie keszujemy put/delete!
            inputStream
        } else if (useCache && kesz.exists()) {
            // już go mamy, więc z niego czytamy
            Logger.d("Query cached locally:" + this.url.toString())
            XenoFileInputStream(kesz)
        } else {
            // nie mamy w keszu
            cachingReq = useCache
            inputStream
        }

        val tekst = XenoFile.streamToText(istream)

        if (cachingReq) {
            XenoFile.cacheText(this.url.toString(), tekst)
        }

        return RestResponse(responseCode, headersToMap(this.headerFields), tekst)
    } else {
        if(errorStream!=null) {
            val tekst = try {
                XenoFile.streamToText(errorStream)
            } catch (x: Exception) {
                Logger.e(x, "Problem")
                "REST Error: Bad status: $responseCode"
            }
            Logger.d("Error stream:$tekst")
            throw IllegalStateException(tekst)
        } else {
            Logger.d("Problem obtaining response for:${this.url} --> $responseCode,$responseMessage")
            throw IllegalStateException(responseMessage)
        }
    }
}

fun buildUrl(protocol: String, host: String, path: String, query: Map<String, String>, port : Int = -1)
 = if(port!=-1) URL(protocol, host, port, path + query.toQueryString()) else URL(protocol, host, path + query.toQueryString())
```

Comment: If you disable ProGuard you can complete the HTTP call?

Comment: Yes, without a problem.

Comment: Specificially - turning off obfuscation get rids of the error. Obfuscated code causes the above. No idea what's so negative about it...

Comment: I have gotten the same error before but wasn't a proguard issue. Was a certification with the web service i was hitting. So I had to bypass that cert in my network call.

Comment: @ssuukk Post the content of proguard-rules.pro file.

Comment: How are you making your requests ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the look of it could be okhttp. Have you tried adding the okhttp proguard rules?

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.* { *;}
-dontwarn okio.
```

Depending on the okhttp version you may need to lose the 3 on okhttp3

Comment: Since I am unable to test it within set time limit I guess I will award the points to only answer received. Thanks for support!